# Deriving instantaneous forward rate from spot rates/ zero rates

Tags: forward-rate, spot-rate

i have the following problem. I have a set of spot rates /zero rates $\{(t,r_t)\}_{t=1}^n$ where $t$ is the time and $r_t$ is the zero rate. How can i calculate with this data the instantaneous forward rate $f(0,t)$ for an arbitrary $t \geq 0$  (i use the term spot rate /zero rate interchangeably, i do hope they are in fact the same thing, if not i have zero rates).

Comment: Can't you use the definition $$f(0,t)=-\frac{\partial \ln P(0,t)}{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{P(0,t)}\frac{\partial P(0,t)}{\partial t},$$ where your zero (or spot) rates $r_t$ give you the bond price curve, $P(0,t)=e^{-r_tt}$.

Comment: Thank You! I didn't knew about this definition of $P(0,t)$ as i'm new to the field (started some days ago)

Comment: @Kevin i have a question abou the formula: if $P(0,t)=e^{-r_tt}$ then shouldn't $ln(P(0,t))=ln(e^{-r_tt})=-r_t \cdot t$ so the derivative is just $r_t$?

Comment: @Bot_Swag: do you have zero rates for different maturities $T_1, T_2, ..., T_m$ observed at each day $t$ or do you have zero rates for one maturity $T_1$ observed at $t$?

Comment: @Kevin i have zero rates for diffrent maturities $T_1,...,T_m$ observed at one day $t=0$